# Document.write alternatives examples

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been using document.write to generate the HTML part of my page, populating it using a loop. For example I need to create 10 of the following things on my page:

```
<div class=" normal" id="1"
    style="text-align:left;
    top:  13px;
    left: 5px;
    height: 10em; 
    width: 12em;">
    <div class = "wrap">
     <div class = "show">
      <strong>New York City
      <p>Status: Cold</p>
      </strong>         
      </div>
     <div class = "noshow">
        <P>0001: Normal</P>             
        </div>

     <div class = "here">
        <P>0001: online</P>
        <P>0002: online</P>

        </div>
        </div>                      
</div>
```

I been doing :

```
<script>
document.write("<div class=\"");
.. you get the idea</script>
```

What is another way to do this with jquery or just not-document.write? Could you also provide short example applied onto the code I have above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jquery .html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) Could be good for this purpose.

```
<script>
   $(function() {
     var htmlString = "<div>.. you get the idea</div>";
     $("body").html(htmlString);
   });
</script>
```

or this will append html:
[.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
<script>
   $(function() {
     var htmlString = "<div>.. you get the idea</div>";
     $("body").append($(htmlString));
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the entire thing in a variable :

say : `var html_content = "<div class=.....";`

and in your loop you can simply use `.append(html_content);`

Answer (score 0):

You could use DOM manipulation to directly query and add node elements to the DOM.

http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/dombasics